# Does SmtpClient.Timeout Property work for asyncronous calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, smtp

In the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx)  it says `Gets or sets a value that specifies the amount of time after which a synchronous Send call times out.`

Does this not work for asynchronous calls?, sometimes my calls are taking far too long and I need a max timeout for them. How can I achieve this with async?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, this can be achieved with a `CancellationTokenSource` with a delay handed in at construction. However, it appears that the Task-based `SendMailAsync` does not support cancellation, but does have a method (`SendAsyncCancel`) that can be used to kill an async send. You could combine this with an expiring `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
async Task Send()
{
    using(SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient())
    using(var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(30000))
    {
        cts.Token.Register(c.SendAsyncCancel);
        await c.SendMailAsync("a@a.a","b@b.b","foo","bar");
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that you get a `TaskCanceledException` instead of the normal `SmtpException`, which you need if you want the status code for error reporting

Comment: @BCA Where's this status code going to come from in the case of a timeout? The whole reason of a timeout is that the server didn't respond.

Comment: Normally, if I set an incorrect password, then call `SendMailAsync()`, it will fail with a `SmtpException` after about 10 seconds. I arrived at this page because I want to shorten that to 5 seconds, and setting the `Timeout` doesn't do the trick. Your solution does indeed accomplish the shortening, but of course now you have no idea of the reason for the failure.

Comment: @BCA you're confusing events that happen at the client with those that happen at the server. If a server takes 10 seconds to tell you that a password is invalid, then nothing you do at the client side will speed that up. The timeout is the moment you give up hope of **any** reply from the server. I suspect you're looking at a throttling mechanism to prevent brute force password attacks. Once again, this happens on the server. It's out of your control

Comment: I realize this is off-topic, but do you have any idea how one would shorten the server's bad-password response to say, 5 seconds?

Comment: @BCA Not a clue. It's likely to be implementation specific. You'd need access and administrative rights to the server. If you're good on this front, I suggest a question over at https://serverfault.com/